# Подключение файла, вывод имени файла, который подключил?

Tags: php

Один файл(скрипт **first.php**) подключает другой (скрипт **second.php**). Возможно ли узнать имя файла [ *first.php* ], подключившего скрипт **second.php**?

Всем спасибо за внимание, то что мне было нужно называется

```
debug_backtrace
```

Answer (score 1):

Достоверно - невозможно.

Варианты:

1. `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` - выдаст путь до исполняемого скрипта.
2. Задать константу\переменную в first.php с именем файла.

Answer (score 1):

Это смотря в где вы это имя файла хотите получить.

**first.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Befor include<br />';
include 'second.php';
echo 'After include<br />';
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$f = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],'/') + 1);
$s = substr(__FILE__,strrpos(__FILE__,'\\') + 1);
if($f != $s) {
echo 'Драсьце! Меня зовут: '.$s.', я подлючен в файл: '.$f.'<br />';
} else {
    echo 'Я сам по себе и никуда не поключен!';
}
```

Теперь, запустив вайл **first.php**, мы будем наблюдать: "*Драсьце! Меня зовут: second.php, я подлючен в файл: first.php*", но если запустим напрямую файл **second.php**, он нас "обманет", сказав: "*Я сам по себе и никуда не поключен!*"

Поэтому [[@Равнодушный](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) абсолютно прав - тут "палка о двух концах"